# Discarding carriage return and/or line feed from a text

Tags: python, string, text, newline

I am writing a program that is reading a number of characters from a text file. However, I am having trouble handling \r and \n and I am wondering if anyone can lend me a hand?

My code snippet is as follows:

```
            with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
                file.seek(self.pointer)
                if self.pointer <= self.file_size:
                    buffer = file.read(self.buffersize)
                    #print("buf" + str(len(buffer)))
                    self.pointer = self.pointer + self.buffersize
                else:
                    buffer = ""
```

When given an input of a file as follows:

```
123456789
abcdefghi
```

I get the following output:

```
123
456
789

ab
bcd
efg
```

when reading three characters at the time (i.e. `self.buffersize == 3´). The leading 'b' in line 5 is what I do not expect... I am running the program in Windows.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What is `self.pointer`?

Comment: You're getting bashed by the Windows newline conventions.  If the file contains "789\r\n", Windows will return to you "789\n", so you think you got 4 chars, but the file pointer needs to move by 5.  I suggest you open the file with "rb".  Either that, or read the whole file into a string and handle it all yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @TimRoberts; I settled for reading the file in binary mode. Very good advice; thanks!!